# What is the most efficient way to generate data matrix through json file like this?

Tags: python, json

I got a file with the format,

`{"A":1, "B":2, "D":3}`

`{"C":1, "E":5, "F":3}`

`{"A":4, "C":5, "F":3}`

So each line of the file is a json object, and its keys could be any subset of size three from `ABCDEF`, what I want to achieve now is to parse a sparse matrix from the file, where I fill NA in each line where the key does not exist for that line.

I used Python and the package `json` to parse the file line by line, but certainly not so neat and efficient, so is there any suggestion on this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but it sure is easy:

```
import pandas as pd

json_string = '[{"A":1, "B":2, "D":3},{"C":1, "E":5, "F":3},{"A":4, "C":5, "F":3}]'
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  5.0  3.0
2  4.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: This will require modification of his file, tho, to turn it into a 'valid JSON' (namely, surrounding it with square brackets and adding commas after each entry).

Comment: This is an amazing approach, though I have to modify the file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might be able to keep the file as is. Check out the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_json.html). Maybe something like `pd.read_json(file_handle, lines=True)`